# how to change the default font for ebook viewer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, windows-explorer, pdf

I use sumatrapdf as my daily viewer for ebooks especially with epub format

To shrink the file size, I usually remove all the font inside fonts folder in epub file.
(for those interested, unlike european fonts, some asian fonts are large in size, including thousands of characters in multi writing systems)

but the viewer's default font is not easy on eyes and is ugly. I want to change it to something better, without embedding a font into epub file.

how do I achieve this? I am not about to move to another viewer when sumatrapdf is by far the fastest in loading the file and light in size on Windows machine.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to choose an epub viewer that supports choosing your own fonts. Have you looked for one that offers that?

Answer (score 1):

Earlier but NOT current versions of SumatraPDF had that ability so download version 3.2 from https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/download-prev

Here is Greek as "Comic Sans MS"
[image]

Comment: I've been keeping the older version installed for that reason. They swapped out the backend at some point and the new back end dosen't support theming https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/docs/Customizing-eBook-UI is the relevant bit. Kinda unfortunate the newer versions don't support it any more